# AttributeError when using python-can (module 'can' has no attribute 'interface')

Tags: python, can-bus

I'm getting an error when running the following code:

```
import can #importing CAN module
import time

bus1 = can.interface.Bus(bustype='vector', channel=0, bitrate=500000,
                         app_name='python-can')
bus2 = can.interface.Bus(bustype='vector', channel=1, bitrate=500000,
                         app_name='python-can')

msg1 = can.Message(arbitration_id = 0xa1,
                   data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                   extended_id = False)
msg2 = can.Message(arbitration_id = 0xa3,
                   data = [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
                   extended_id = False)
bus1.send(msg1)
time.sleep(1.0)
bus2.send(msg2)
bus1.shutdown()
bus2.shutdown()
```

I can import the CAN module, but then I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'can' has no attribute 'interface'
```

I am trying to send dummy messages to virtual CAN. How can I fix this error?

Comment: What happens if you remove `.interface`? Just `bus1 = can.Bus(...)`?

Comment: It throwing below error AttributeError: module 'can' has no attribute 'Bus' @JosSeldenthuis

Answer (score 3):

I made a silly mistake and had a file called:

```
can.py
```

in the same folder! I was obviously importing the wrong file, so renaming this file fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue today while using python-can 3.3.3, and resolved it by updating to 3.3.4 which was released not that long ago.

Since the package is still being worked on, it looks like they accidentally released a broken version with 3.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

In case that issue happens with pyinstaller 4.0 after the .py packed as .exe, add below line to the code;

```
import can.interfaces.vector
```

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally did a `pip install can` instead of `pip install python-can`, which led me to this error too. Remove the `can` package and try again with `python-can`.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded the python-can library to the earlier version and it worked
pip install python-can==X.Y.Z
This is the command I used where X Y and Z is the version we want to download

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).