# AttributeError: module 'can' has no attribute 'interface' with version 3.3.4

Tags: python-3.x, can-bus

I am trying to send can message using can-python library
Getting below error
AttributeError: module 'can' has no attribute 'interface'

can-python version :3.3.4
python version :3

code

```
import can

def send():
bus = can.interface.Bus()
msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x68005,data=[0x10,0x11,0x12],is_extended_id=True)
try:
     bus.send(msg)
     print("Message sent on {}".format(bus.channel_info))
except can.CanError:
    print("Message NOT sent")'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send()
```

I followed this
[AttributeError when using python-can (module 'can' has no attribute 'interface')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64022196/attributeerror-when-using-python-can-module-can-has-no-attribute-interface)

didnt work for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError when using python-can (module 'can' has no attribute 'interface')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64022196/attributeerror-when-using-python-can-module-can-has-no-attribute-interface)

Comment: @HantsanialaEléo,answer mentioned in the post doesnot  work for me

Answer (score 1):

Try to downgrade to python-can to version 2 and upgrade after that. I don't know how but that fixed the error. But after that you must specify a bus type or you'll get `NotImplementedError: Invalid CAN Bus Type - None`.

Here is what I've done :

```sh
$ pip install python-can==2
$ pip install python-can --upgrade
```

Comment: Just figured out I had named file as can.py which was throwing error , I changed it other name  and worked, no other changes.